# Add paragraph tags to comments

Tags: comments

The line breaks on my comments are not being considered. I've inspected the elements in google chrome and it seems that wordpress is not adding paragraph tags `<p>` to them, while in the body text it does.

The comments.php in my template has the following snippet:

```
<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments(); ?>
</ol>
```

No options of [wp_list_comments()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) seems to be related to this.

Also, in the file `default-filter.php` I have the line

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpautop', 30 );
```

So I don't understand why it's not adding the tags.

Is anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: Disable all plugins, switch to TwentyEleven. Does it still happen?

Comment: @toscho - Thanks for your comment. It was indeed a plugin that was causing this issue. More specifically Crayon Syntax Highlighter 1.9.1

Comment: @kunigami sorry about that, other users also reported this and it's fixed in 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @toscho I've found the problem.

Crayon Syntax Highlighter 1.9.1 seems to have a [bug](http://ak.net84.net/projects/crayon-syntax-highlighter/). While it's not fixed, one workaround that is reasonable for me is unchecking the "Allow Crayons inside comments" option.

Answer (score 1):

**You should structure your comment so it would use the "comment_text" build in function  or even easier should use a fallback function that would structure your comment...**

*For example in twenty ten it looks like this:*

```
function twentyten_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
$GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
    case '' :
?>
<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
    <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="comment-author vcard">
        <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 40 ); ?>
        <?php printf( __( '%s <span class="says">says:</span>', 'twentyten' ), sprintf( '<cite class="fn">%s</cite>', get_comment_author_link() ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .comment-author .vcard -->
    <?php if ( $comment->comment_approved == '0' ) : ?>
        <em><?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'twentyten' ); ?></em>
        <br />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ); ?>">
        <?php
            /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
            printf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'twentyten' ), get_comment_date(),  get_comment_time() ); ?></a><?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)', 'twentyten' ), ' ' );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .comment-meta .commentmetadata -->

    <div class="comment-body"><?php comment_text(); ?></div>

    <div class="reply">
        <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .reply -->
</div><!-- #comment-##  -->

<?php
        break;
    case 'pingback'  :
    case 'trackback' :
?>
<li class="post pingback">
    <p><?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'twentyten' ); ?> <?php comment_author_link(); ?><?php edit_comment_link( __('(Edit)', 'twentyten'), ' ' ); ?></p>
<?php
        break;
endswitch;
}
endif;
```

**so... you can include this code or embed it in your functions.php then make

it a callback default like so.. :**

```
wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentyten_comment' ) );
```

.
**The difference is this part:**

```
comment_text()
```

.
You can read here about: [comment_text()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_text)

.
Hope this helps ;)
Best of luck, Sagive.

Comment: The default `wp_list_comments()` should already work just fine. There is no need to introduce extra code into the problem.

Comment: so... what might be the problem? cuz' i once solved this using this method... would love to know how to short-solve this when this happens.

Comment: Some other code removed the default filter for `'wpautop'`. I should have closed the question until the missing information is added.

Comment: ok... i guess its a work in progress to get to what information is missing :) - thanks for the info